# Why does this one SVG file cause Libreoffice Writer to slow down?

Tags: libreoffice, svg

I have a LibreOffice Writer file that contains two SVG files. Both SVG files are about 200Kb in size, and neither contain anything other than vectors, so far as I know. There are no embedded PNGs or other data.

One of the two files causes LibreOffice Writer to slow down. The window goes grey, my CPU usage monitor goes up. This happens every time I scroll past the image, or save or open the document. If I remove that image, the problem goes away. I have tried removing it and re-inserting it, as well as opening it in Inkscape to look for any problems, but I can't make any determination as why this SVG is problematic.

The other SVG embeds into LibreOffice Writer just fine. No slowdowns, no CPU usage. So, I suspect the problem is not with Writer, but with the one SVG file.

I have no idea how to diagnose what might be wrong with an SVG file that might make it problematic when embedding it in LibreOffice. Is there some tool I can use, or some method that would shed light on this situation?

Comment: How do they open in Inkscape, the goto tool for SVGs?

Comment: @muru, as mentioned in the second paragraph of my question, I have opened them in Inkscape, and there aren't any problems there. At least, none that I can determine. If there's a particular tool or function in Inkscape that I can use to probe the file, please let me know.

Comment: LO has had recurring issues with vector files over the past few releases. I would recommend participating in [this bug report](https://www.libreoffice.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58420) and providing your SVG image as a sample file.